# "Pickable" property in catia V5 drawing using automation

Tags: vba, catia, caa

How can I access the "Pickable property" in Graphic property tab of text, table or simple lines in Catia VBA.

This image shows the properties of simple line and the thing marked in Red is what i want to use
[image: This image shows the properties of simple line and the thing marked in Red is what i want to use]

Thank you.

Comment: Please have a look on the methods _SetPick_ and _GetPick_ of the _VisProperties_-object fir the selected elements.

Comment: @Shrotter I am starting to feel dumb now :( ..... anyway, Thank you for the response, this helped a lot.